# After changing a property on a LayoutParams object, do I need to call setLayoutParams again?

Tags: android, layoutparams

I have a View (containing an ad) that I need to scale to fit the screen width at a certain point in time (after the ad is loaded). So I have a method `setHeight(myView)` that calculates the correct height for the given screen width and changes the LayoutParams of the View accordingly. The crucial part of the code is this:

```
LayoutParams params = myView.getLayoutParams();
int width = myView.getWidth();
if (params != null && width > 0) {
    params.height = (int) Math.round(ratio * width);
}
```

This seems to work for the most part, but sometimes the view is not scaled. It seems to only consistenly work if I add the following line at the bottom:

```
myView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This seems to make sense, too, since Android Views call `requestLayout()` in their `setLayoutParams()` method. Conversely, I see no way how a change in a public field (`params.height`) would trigger a layout change.

On the other hand, I repeatedly find tutorials on the net where the params are simply changed and then not set to the view again.

So, my question is: Is it correct that, to immediately update the layout after changing a property of the LayoutParams, I need to call `setLayoutParams` again? And that simply changing the property will only lead to a layout change at some later point in time when the layout change is triggered from elsewhere?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A change to the layout params only take effect on the next layout pass.

- `requestLayout()` schedules a layout pass
- `setLayoutParams()` calls `requestLayout()` as you have observed
- Sometimes a layout pass is scheduled by some other means. For example, immediately after inflation the layout params have also been inflated and the measure/layout message has just been posted to the UI thread message queue for later processing.

So, to be safe, call `requestLayout()` always after touching the layout params. `setLayoutParams()` works, too, though it's not strictly necessary when modifying the params in-place.

Comment: Since LayoutParams are used to communicate from the child to the parent, shouldn't we need to call requestLayout on the parent once the child's LayoutParams change?

Comment: @vlazzle Layout requests on children propagate to the parent as well.

Comment: Oh yeah I see that [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L21920). Thanks @laalto!

Comment: Depending on the use case, you may want to do that call on the UI thread. e.g. `myView.post { myView.layoutParams = params }`

Answer (score 5):

In **Kotlin** you can use KTX extension to update `LayoutParams`

```
view.updateLayoutParams { height = newValue }
```